# Is there a way to use aws managed key (for sqs) in an IAM policy statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-kms

Tried to use alias arn in an IAM policy statement but it did not work.

Later I came across the aws [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/cmks-in-iam-policies.html#) and it seems like I cannot use a key id, alias name, or alias ARN to identify a KMS key in an IAM policy statement.

I tried to use the alias arn first (no dice).

```
PolicyDocument:
  Statement:
    - Effect: Allow
      Principal:
        Service: s3.amazonaws.com
      Action:
        - kms:Encrypt
        - kms:Decrypt
      Resource: arn:aws:kms:<region>:<account-id>:key/alias/aws/sqs
```

S3 was not able to send events to the sqs queue.

Answer (score 0):

@skumar Can you describe your scenario more precisely?
As far as I understood, S3 should send an event notification to SQS message, right? If so, I think you use the default SQS KMS Key, since "alias/aws/sqs" is the default. You don't need to add the IAM Policy Statement you mentioned above to your IAM Policy. Tbh. it is not clear to me where you want to add this policy.

Check out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/grant-destinations-permissions-to-s3.html

Focus on **IAM policy for a destination SQS queue** even if I do not exactly know what you want to do. Section **AWS KMS key policy** is irrelevant for you, since you want to use the default KMS SQS Key.